# How to remove space between borders of parent and child element and collapse them

Tags: html, css

I am facing problem with the borders of `div` and `h2`. I tried everything to remove the little space at the bottom of
`h2` but failed. Also, I wish that the border of `h2` overlap the border of `div`.

```html
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <style>
        * {
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
          box-sizing: border-box;
        }
          div {
            width: 80%;
            margin: 0 auto;
            margin-top: 100px;
            border: 2px solid black;
          }
          div h2 {
            border: 2px solid black;
          }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div>
          <h2>Level 2 Heading</h2>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

[image]

Comment: is there any zoom active on your browser?

Comment: Yeah I'm not seeing the gap in Chrome or FF

Comment: No there is no zoom on my browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed that problem occurs based on the zoom in or zoom out. If you zoom in the problem will disappear if you zoom out it will happen again. But anyway.

if you use the property `outline` instead of `border` for the `div` the problem will disappear at all screen sizes. More info about  [outline property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline)

[image: result]

CSS I changed

```
 div {
        width: 80%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        margin-top: 100px;
        outline: 2px solid black;
    }

    div h2 {
        border: 2px solid red;
        margin: 0;
    }
```

Or you could just give the container `div` border of `4px` if you want it that thick and remove the `h2` border completely and the opposite is correct.

Comment: Thanks Ahmad Dalao Sir, outline property works for me.

Comment: Great. Glad to hear that.